# plot in Pandas immediately closes

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have a problem of plotting the data. I run the following python code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("table.csv")

values = df["blah"]
values.plot()
print 1

df['blahblah'].plot()
print 2
```

My output is:

```
50728417:Desktop evgeniy$ python test2.py
1
2
50728417:Desktop evgeniy$
```

And finally I see how launches python icon( picture of rocket, by the way , what is it?) in my Dock( using mac os), and then it disappears. Printed numbers 1,2 show me that no error exist. So have no idea what to do next.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem is that pandas's `DataFrame.plot` does not block. Therefore the figures are closed when your program ends. Pandas uses matplotlib internally so you can circumvent this by calling `matplotlib.pyplot.show` with `block=True` like so:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("table.csv")

values = df["blah"]
values.plot()
print 1

df['blahblah'].plot()
print 2
plt.show(block=True)
```

This way the program will only end when `plt.show` returns, which is after you closed all figures.