# Camelot Matplotlib window suddenly closes

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-camelot

```
import camelot
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib

file = 'foo.pdf'
tables = camelot.read_pdf(file, pages='all', flavor='stream')
camelot.plot(tables[0], kind='text').show()
```

The matplot window opens and suddenly closes in a flash without any user input whatsoever.

I want the window to remain open to examine the contents.

Edit: I am using Windows 11 and Python 3.9, running the code on Pycharm and it's the system interpreter rather than a virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you ever found your answer, but I will attach what I have found from the following answer by swenzel: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33062819

The plot is opening in a non-blocking window which disappears as soon as the script finishes. You can override this by importing matplotlib and using plot.show(block=True) at the end to show the window as a blocking window, which will keep the script from continuing until closed. See his code snippet below.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("table.csv")

values = df["blah"]
values.plot()
print 1

df['blahblah'].plot()
print 2
plt.show(block=True)
```

Your code rewritten would look like the following:

```
import camelot
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

file = 'foo.pdf'
tables = camelot.read_pdf(file, pages='all', flavor='stream')
camelot.plot(tables[0], kind='text')
plt.show(block=True)
```